# Setting cookie for a URL Request in Flash? (Argument Error 2096)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cookies, http-headers

Is there any possible way to set the cookie header for a URLRequest in Flash? What I have now is:

`r.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("cookie", "a=1");`

And that gives me this lovely error:

`ArgumentError: Error #2096: The HTTP request header cookie cannot be set via ActionScript.`

Is there any way to get around this restriction? The server I am connecting to requires that some auth variables be in the cookie of the request (which worked for other implementations, such as a client on the Android platform).

Thanks!
-Esa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Flash in a browser.
Short answer: No.
Long answer: You could use JavaScript via ExternalInterface which has access to cookies.